# Why is MySQL taking up all the space on my server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, command-line-interface, ubuntu-20.04

I have a server with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and MySQL 8

My system drive is normally around 11gb out of the 20gb available.

For a week my database has used everything.

Why is MySQL taking up all the space on my server ?

Why the database went from 1.4gb to 14gb

```
ubuntu@ov-376Gf2 ~ $ sudo du -h -d 1 /var/lib/mysql
1.5M    /var/lib/mysql/performance_schema
84K /var/lib/mysql/sys
622M    /var/lib/mysql/www_s1biose_com
164K    /var/lib/mysql/#innodb_temp
36K /var/lib/mysql/mysql
14G /var/lib/mysql
```

and

```
ubuntu@ov-376Gf2 ~ $ sudo ls -larth /var/lib/mysql
total 14G
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql 4.0K Sep  7 17:39  performance_schema
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql   56 Sep  7 17:39  auto.cnf
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql 1.7K Sep  7 17:39  ca-key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql 1.1K Sep  7 17:39  ca.pem
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql 1.7K Sep  7 17:39  server-key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql 1.1K Sep  7 17:39  server-cert.pem
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql 1.7K Sep  7 17:39  client-key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql 1.1K Sep  7 17:39  client-cert.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql  452 Sep  7 17:39  public_key.pem
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql 1.7K Sep  7 17:39  private_key.pem
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql 4.0K Sep  7 17:39  mysql
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql 4.0K Sep  7 17:39  sys
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root     0 Sep  7 17:39  debian-5.7.flag
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  179 Sep  7 17:39  binlog.000001
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  403 Sep  7 17:39  binlog.000002
drwxr-xr-x 53 root  root  4.0K Sep  7 17:42  ..
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 1.2K Sep  7 17:48  binlog.000003
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 3.3K Sep  7 17:48  ib_buffer_pool
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql 4.0K Sep  7 17:49 '#innodb_temp'
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  12M Sep  7 17:49  ibtmp1
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 102M Sep  7 21:44  binlog.000004
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  7 21:44  binlog.000005
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  7 21:47  binlog.000006
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  7 22:11  binlog.000007
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 104M Sep  8 00:34  binlog.000008
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  8 02:49  binlog.000009
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  8 09:45  binlog.000010
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  8 16:25  binlog.000011
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  8 23:00  binlog.000012
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  23M Sep  9 00:00  binlog.000013
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  9 01:45  binlog.000014
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  9 02:13  binlog.000015
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  9 02:39  binlog.000016
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  9 02:47  binlog.000017
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 102M Sep  9 03:10  binlog.000018
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 107M Sep  9 03:18  binlog.000019
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 102M Sep  9 03:30  binlog.000020
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 102M Sep  9 03:42  binlog.000021
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  9 03:52  binlog.000022
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  9 03:52  binlog.000023
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  9 05:51  binlog.000024
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  9 10:43  binlog.000025
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  9 16:00  binlog.000026
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  9 17:33  binlog.000027
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  9 20:15  binlog.000028
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep  9 23:20  binlog.000029
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  34M Sep 10 00:00  binlog.000030
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 10 06:25  binlog.000031
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 10 14:30  binlog.000032
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 10 18:20  binlog.000033
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 10 20:59  binlog.000034
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 10 23:06  binlog.000035
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 10 23:37  binlog.000036
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  76M Sep 11 00:00  binlog.000037
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 105M Sep 11 00:04  binlog.000038
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 108M Sep 11 00:16  binlog.000039
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 106M Sep 11 00:19  binlog.000040
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 11 02:33  binlog.000041
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 104M Sep 11 03:36  binlog.000042
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 11 03:42  binlog.000043
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 11 05:14  binlog.000044
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 11 12:11  binlog.000045
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 11 19:36  binlog.000046
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 11 20:18  binlog.000047
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  86M Sep 12 00:00  binlog.000048
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 12 01:49  binlog.000049
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 12 02:15  binlog.000050
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 12 07:00  binlog.000051
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 12 12:15  binlog.000052
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 102M Sep 12 12:17  binlog.000053
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 104M Sep 12 12:38  binlog.000054
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 12 12:44  binlog.000055
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 12 13:28  binlog.000056
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 12 15:08  binlog.000057
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 108M Sep 12 15:27  binlog.000058
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 12 17:50  binlog.000059
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  91M Sep 13 00:00  binlog.000060
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 107M Sep 13 04:18  binlog.000061
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 13 04:19  binlog.000062
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 13 04:45  binlog.000063
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 13 11:30  binlog.000064
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 13 15:08  binlog.000065
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 13 17:45  binlog.000066
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  87M Sep 14 00:00  binlog.000067
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 02:24  binlog.000068
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 02:26  binlog.000069
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 02:39  binlog.000070
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 02:55  binlog.000071
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 03:09  binlog.000072
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 105M Sep 14 03:14  binlog.000073
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 03:20  binlog.000074
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 03:42  binlog.000075
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 102M Sep 14 03:44  binlog.000076
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 102M Sep 14 03:48  binlog.000077
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 03:49  binlog.000078
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 04:28  binlog.000079
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 04:32  binlog.000080
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 04:40  binlog.000081
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 04:44  binlog.000082
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 105M Sep 14 04:45  binlog.000083
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 04:48  binlog.000084
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 04:54  binlog.000085
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 06:00  binlog.000086
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 11:31  binlog.000087
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 105M Sep 14 13:56  binlog.000088
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 104M Sep 14 13:58  binlog.000089
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 105M Sep 14 13:59  binlog.000090
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 103M Sep 14 14:03  binlog.000091
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 14:11  binlog.000092
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 104M Sep 14 14:28  binlog.000093
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 15:07  binlog.000094
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 16:13  binlog.000095
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 17:39  binlog.000096
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 103M Sep 14 17:54  binlog.000097
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 17:55  binlog.000098
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 18:30  binlog.000099
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 14 23:16  binlog.000100
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  14M Sep 15 00:00  binlog.000101
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 15 03:56  binlog.000102
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 15 06:00  binlog.000103
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 15 13:15  binlog.000104
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 15 20:00  binlog.000105
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  86M Sep 16 00:00  binlog.000106
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 16 02:33  binlog.000107
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 16 03:23  binlog.000108
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 107M Sep 16 06:54  binlog.000109
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 16 08:51  binlog.000110
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 16 12:24  binlog.000111
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 16 16:27  binlog.000112
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 16 17:04  binlog.000113
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 16 18:53  binlog.000114
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 16 23:18  binlog.000115
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  28M Sep 17 00:00  binlog.000116
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 17 06:15  binlog.000117
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 17 12:30  binlog.000118
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 17 18:15  binlog.000119
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  78M Sep 18 00:00  binlog.000120
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 18 06:00  binlog.000121
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 18 13:45  binlog.000122
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 18 14:23  binlog.000123
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 18 19:57  binlog.000124
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  51M Sep 19 00:00  binlog.000125
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 19 08:21  binlog.000126
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 19 17:00  binlog.000127
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  70M Sep 20 00:00  binlog.000128
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 20 10:15  binlog.000129
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 20 22:00  binlog.000130
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 8.2M Sep 20 23:53 '#ib_16384_1.dblwr'
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  86M Sep 21 00:00  binlog.000131
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 105M Sep 21 01:58  binlog.000132
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 21 02:04  binlog.000133
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 21 03:58  binlog.000134
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 21 06:15  binlog.000135
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 21 13:53  binlog.000136
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql  52K Sep 21 14:56  www_s1biose_com
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 104M Sep 21 15:41  binlog.000137
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 21 20:59  binlog.000138
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  49M Sep 22 00:00  binlog.000139
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 22 07:00  binlog.000140
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 101M Sep 22 11:15  binlog.000141
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 2.3K Sep 22 11:15  binlog.index
drwx------  7 mysql mysql 4.0K Sep 22 11:15  .
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  36M Sep 22 15:13  mysql.ibd
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  79M Sep 22 15:13  binlog.000142
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  13M Sep 22 15:13  undo_002
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  15M Sep 22 15:13  undo_001
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  48M Sep 22 15:13  ib_logfile1
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  12M Sep 22 15:13  ibdata1
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql 192K Sep 22 15:13 '#ib_16384_0.dblwr'
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  48M Sep 22 15:13  ib_logfile0
```

Comment: why do you try to do an ls -larth /var/lib/mysql and check which files are growing?

Comment: @c4f4t0r Thanks, I updated my question but I don't know what to do

Comment: Is this database used? In my enterprise, some databases weight over 1 terabyte, so gaining 10Go on a frequently used database doesn't surprise me.

Comment: @LeRouteur Yes for a small drupal 8 site before updating to MySQL 8 I did not have this problem. What are these binlog files ?

Comment: Do you have lots of write queries?  Or do they modify lots of rows?  There may be some optimizations in those areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are binary transaction logs. [You can purge them](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/purge-binary-logs.html), but you should actually read into their purpose and make an informed decision about how many you should keep, based on the criticality of your data. [You can control a lot of their behavior in the configuration options.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html)

Comment: I only have a database on a single server. I am not replicating. Are these files useful ?

Comment: @20f2c98f50 Probably not, but transaction logs are useful for recovering data between backups, so you should sync your purges with your backup strategy.

Comment: For backups, I just do a command line to export the database

Comment: @20f2c98f50 The point is that the transaction logs could provide more granular restore points.

Comment: "For backups, I just do a command line to export the database" - that is NOT a backup. Backups should always go to offline separate systems without direct copy functionality. Ask anyone who lost data because every reachable data was encrypted by ransomware.

Comment: Exactly. With a binary tx log you can restore down to the last transaction - hence they should alyways at least be on a separate drive. They contain the changes since the last backup.

Comment: @TomTom I save my database exports with this https://www.infomaniak.com/en/swiss-backup How can I reduce the duration of the logs? From 30 days by default to 7 days ?

Comment: @Satanicpuppy I save my database exports with this infomaniak.com/en/swiss-backup How can I reduce the duration of the logs? From 30 days by default to 7 days ?

Comment: Specifically, see `expire_logs_days` and `binlog_expire_logs_seconds`.

Comment: @Rick James Ok thank you, I have updated 1 day. Will the current files be purged automatically?

Comment: @20f2c98f50 - I think so, but perhaps only when it is ready to build a new binlog -- which seems to happen every few hours.